# Passing ID to Controller from Object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, parameter-passing

I'm trying to simply pass an object (dgroup) to another controller's (tplans) index action.  I'm performing a lookup based on a foreign key, so I am passing it an object id that it must filter on, but it doesn't seem to be working.  This is my code:

Within the dgroup's index.html:

```
<% @dgroups.each do |dgroup| %>
<tr>
<td><%= dgroup.id %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Show TPlans', tplans_path(dgroup) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_dgroup_path(dgroup) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', dgroup, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Within tplan's controller:

```
def index
  @dgid = Dgroup.find(params[:id])
  @tplans = @dgid.tplans

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @tplans }
end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?  Note that If I replace:

```
@dgid = Dgroup.find(params[:id])
```

with

```
@dgid = Dgroup.find(1)
```

the code works, just obviously does not find the object that I want.  I was just doing this to make sure the controller code was structured correctly.

Comment: Please can you display the route for dgroup index and edit action?

Comment: you probably need to use `params[:dgroup_id]`, depending on your route

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your `params[:id]` is coming nil.

try

```
 <td><%= link_to 'Show TPlans', tplans_path(:id => dgroup.id) %></td>
```

you will get it in your index method.

the reason is if you rake:routes you will see

```
 tplans GET    /tplans(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"tplas"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an object dgroup to your links instead of passing an id.

Try

```
<% @dgroups.each do |dgroup| %>
<tr>
<td><%= dgroup = dgroup.id %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Show TPlans', tplans_path(dgroup) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_dgroup_path(dgroup) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', dgroup, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% @dgroups.each do |dgroup| %>
<tr>
<td><%= dgroup.id %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Show TPlans', tplans_path(dgroup.id) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_dgroup_path(dgroup.id) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', dgroup.id, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```